# Set a list item in listview to auto web link and nake the rest of the text view clickable

Tags: android, android-layout

How to set a list item in listview to auto web link and nake the rest of the text view clickable. Can this be done directly in xml file? I tried like this android:autoLink="web" , but the rest of the text view is not clickable? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Clickable span.
This is an [example](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring) of Clickable Span

Comment: but i am using online contents and using a text holder in another class.also i am getting arraylist only there. so will it work